# Optimizing Matrix Traversal/General Code Optimization

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have two matrices. One is of size (CxK) and another is of size (SxK) (where S,C, and K all have the potential to be very large). I want to combine these an output matrix using the cosine similarity function (would be of size [CxS]). When I run my code, it takes a very long time to produce an output, and I was wondering if there is any way to optimize what I currently have. [Note, the two input matrices are often very sparse]

I was previously traversing each matrix using two `for index,row` loops, but I have since switched to the while loops, which improved my run time significantly.

```
A #this is one of my input matrices (pandas dataframe)
B #this is my second input matrix (pandas dataframe)
C = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col_1'  ,'col_2'  ,'col_3'])

i=0
k=0
while i <= 5:
    col_1 = A.iloc[i].get('label_A')
    while k < 5:
        col_2 = B.iloc[k].get('label_B')
        propensity = cosine_similarity([A.drop('label_A', axis=1)\
            .iloc[i]], [B.drop('label_B',axis=1).iloc[k]])
        d = {'col_1':[col_1], 'col_2':[col_2], 'col_3':[propensity[0][0]]}
        to_append = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
        C = C.append(to_append)
        k += 1
    k = 0
    i += 1
```

Right now I have the loops to run on only 5 items from each matrix, producing a 5x5 matrix, but I would obviously like this to work for very large inputs. This is the first time I have done anything like this so please let me know if any facet of code can be improved (data types used to hold matrices, how to traverse them, updating the output matrix, etc.).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the cosine_similarity function you are using from sklearn?

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html

Comment: @jTables yes, sorry didn't import it. I am passing it a keyword vector from each input matrix and storing the result in an output matrix.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have time to answer this today, if it's still unanswered when I have some time I'll look into it. In general looping over dataframes will be slow, using apply will be much faster. I have also used the underlying numpy array (which you can get with .values) if I don't need any pandas functionality. This has always proven faster than using a dataframe for my applications. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done much more easyly and way faster by passing the **whole arrays** to `cosine_similarity` after you move the labels to the index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import time

c = 50
s = 50
k = 100

A = pd.DataFrame( np.random.rand(c,k))
B = pd.DataFrame( np.random.rand(s,k))
A['label_A'] = [f'A{i}' for i in range(c)]
B['label_B'] = [f'B{i}' for i in range(s)]
C = pd.DataFrame()

# your program
start = time.time()
i=0
k=0
while i < c:
    col_1 = A.iloc[i].get('label_A')
    while k < s:
        col_2 = B.iloc[k].get('label_B')
        propensity = cosine_similarity([A.drop('label_A', axis=1)\
            .iloc[i]], [B.drop('label_B',axis=1).iloc[k]])
        d = {'col_1':[col_1], 'col_2':[col_2], 'col_3':[propensity[0][0]]}
        to_append = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
        C = C.append(to_append)
        k += 1
    k = 0
    i += 1
print(f'elementwise: {time.time() - start:7.3f} s')

# my solution
start = time.time()
A = A.set_index('label_A')
B = B.set_index('label_B')
C1 = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(A, B), index=A.index, columns=B.index).stack().rename('col_3')
C1.index.rename(['col_1','col_2'], inplace=True)
C1 = C1.reset_index()
print(f'whole array: {time.time() - start:7.3f} s')

# verification
assert(C[['col_1','col_2']].to_numpy()==C1[['col_1','col_2']].to_numpy()).all()\
       and np.allclose(C.col_3.to_numpy(), C1.col_3.to_numpy())
```

Comment: So this works amazingly, but one other question. I am trying to do this to for item to item recommendation as well, and when i set the index and columns of the dataframe to the same value like this `C1 = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(A, A), index=A.index, columns=A.index).stack().reset_index()` I get the error `ValueError: cannot insert A.index, already exists`. Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: @kshoe94 I updated my answer so that it works for this case too by renaming the columns before resetting the index.